# RewriteRule capturing second instance of regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to prevent blind redirects to domains that don't belong to my site. I am referencing a rewritemap that has a list of approved domains. This has been working as expected except in the following scenerio. My regex is capturing the string from first targetPage= all the way to the second .com and I need it to stop at the first .com so I can capture domain.

Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)(url=|target=|targeturl=|targetpage=|redirecturl=)(https?)[\%A-Z0-9]*2F(.*\.com|.*\.net|.*\.org)/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond ${validDomains:%4} !validdomain
```

When url being hit is:
`https://mysite.domain.com/secure/SigninServlet?targetPage=https://mysite.domain.com/mysite/pages/msb/myAccount/correct.jsp?RNRedirectUrl=DSP&referrerUrl=https://mysite.domain.com/mysite/pages/msb/user/signinrn.jsp`

The %4 reference value returned is:
`mysite.domain.com/mysite/pages/msb/myAccount/correct.jsp?RNRedirectUrl=DSP&referrerUrl=https://mysite.domain.com`

If I change the referrerUrl to end in .cim then i capture just mysite.domain.com

How can I modify the regex to only see first domain not second?

Comment: Why not use `[a-z0-9.]` as the domain name capture? Why do you want a `%` in a domain name, what would it encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(url|target|targeturl|targetpage|redirecturl)=(https?)[\%A-Z0-9]*2F([^&]*?\.(?:com|net|org)) [NC]
RewriteCond ${validDomains:%4} !validdomain
```

Comment: when updating to that it doesn't match the rewritecond

Comment: because the targetpage wasn't encoded - your suggestion of ([^&]*?\.(?:com|net|org)) does work - i just had to put it in my non-encoded section and it does work like below

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*[&?]|)(url=|target=|targeturl=|targetpage=|redirecturl=)(https?):?//([^&]*?\.(?:com|net|org)) [NC]